# Ceiling fan light turns on sometimes, sometimes it doesn’t

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan, light

I have an old ceiling fan and the lights sometimes will not turn on even after pulling the pull chain many times. I’ve noticed that in the morning/afternoon it usually will turn on with 1 pull, but in the evening/night I could pull the chain 100 times and it won’t turn on. What could be causing it to work fine only sometimes and how can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First check that the bulb is in tight. If that is ok check the power to the switch when the light will not come on. If there is power, your switch needs replaced.  If there is no power the fan needs to be removed and all connections checked even at the wall switch. Not to be alarming, but if the power comes and goes with conditions there can be a hazardous condition.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the pull chain switch has a bad internal contact.

You could replace it, but requires opening the fan/light housing.

You can get those pull chain switches at hardware store like HD.

Did I say turn off the Circuit breaker first.